# Unix socket Multiple client group chat with client name in c

Tags: c, multithreading, unix-socket

So far everything have been working perfectly. Just the problem I've been having is that I can't think of a way of assigning or i would say giving names to the clients who are connect to the server so that other clients who know is wrote a message

server:

```
while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    //FD_ZERO(&write_set);

    FD_SET(fd, &read_set);
    //FD_SET(fd, &write_set);

    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) { //at first this part will not excute
        FD_SET(clients[i], &read_set);
    }

    select(fd + num_clients + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);


    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set)) {
        if ((clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
            perror("accept error");
            continue;
        }
        printf("we got a connection!\n");
    }


    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {

        if (FD_ISSET(clients[i], &read_set)) {
            msg = read(clients[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (msg > 0) {
                int savedclnt = clients[i];
                printf("client %d says: %s\n", i, buf);

                for (int p = 0; p<num_clients; p++)
                {
                    if (clients[p] != savedclnt) {
                        //write("from %d",clients[p]);
                        //char msg2 = strcat(clients[i],msg);
                        write(clients[p], buf, msg);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you show? What is your question? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The problem I've been having is that I can't think of a way of making the server write every message that a client sends over the socket into all other clients. I've read other similar posts in here and it was helpless.

Comment: To begin with I suggest you either try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or at least step through the code line by line in a debugger. That's because you have some glaring problems regarding your thread handling. As for your problem, keep a collection of all connected clients, and when you read input loop over this collection to write to all other clients. An array or a list of file descriptors is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're doing, you don't really need threads. From personal experience, a single threaded server would do the job just fine. Instead of having the main body wrap around a call to `accept()` you should use `select()` to see which file descriptors have input, something along the lines of...

```
fd_set readfds;
struct timeval timeout;
unsigned int num_clients;
unsigned int clients[100];
while(1)
  {
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(sock, &readfds);
  for(i=0; i<num_clients; i++)
    {
    FD_SET(clients[i],&readfds);
    }
  timeout.tv_sec=1;
  timeout.tv_usec=0;
  select(max_fds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if(FD_ISSET(sock,&readfds))
    {
    clients[num_clients++] = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,&size);
    }
  for(i=0;i<num_clients;i++)
    {
    if(FD_ISSET(clients[i],&readfds))
      {
      int err=read(clients[i],buf,1000);
      if(err>0)
        {
        for(p=0;p<num_clients;p++)
          {
          write(clients[i],buf,err);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That code is just an example and needs error checking to see if a client has disconnected, a way of updating the list of clients and seeing if a client is ready to receive data. But hopefully it gives you the basic idea of where to go?

Comment: i am not really familiar with select() method but i update my code with a single thread as u suggested but still not giving me what i want

Comment: the `select()` function is waiting for at most a second or until one of the file descriptions in the bit set readfds has some input.

Comment: @johnleonardonwuzuruigbo Your code hasn't changed in any meaningful way. It's still creating a new thread every time a client connects. It maybe doesn't help that you've called a variable `new_server` when it should be `new_client` as that is what `accept()` is returning - a file descriptor for a new client.

Comment: Thank you very much... it works with select... almost same logic in the previous code i had but with select(  this time.

Comment: now i have another problem..i have modified the code that i posted. is there a possibility to assign names to client so that other client will know who connected and who sent a message?

Comment: you probably should have started a new question and accepted this answer rather than editing everything as now it doesn't make sense :/